# Getting a 400 Response Spotify API Python

Tags: python, api, jupyter-notebook, python-requests, spotify

I am trying to use requests.get with the Spotify API and I can't figure out why I keep getting a 400 response. I am working in an .ipynb file in Jupyter Lab running locally. I read [these](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.1.2) [documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/#response-schema) but I cannot find anything relevant.

This is the response I keep getting:

> {'error': {'status': 400,
> 'message': 'Only valid bearer authentication supported'}}

Here is my code:

```
# secrets.py contains important secret variables
from secrets import *
import base64
import requests
import json

# function posts to /api/token endpoint and returns access token
def spotify_get_access_token(client_id, client_secret):
    url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'
    auth = base64.b64encode(f'{client_id}:{client_secret}'.encode('ascii')).decode('ascii')
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Basic {auth}'}
    data = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}
    return requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data).json()['access_token']

spotify_access_token = spotify_get_access_token(spotify_client_id, spotify_client_secret)

# function gets from specified endpoint and returns response as json
def spotify_get(endpoint, params):
    url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1' + endpoint
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer: {spotify_access_token}'}
    return requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)

print(spotify_get('/artists/2xvtxDNInKDV4AvGmjw6d1/albums', {'include_groups': 'album'}).json())
```

This is what was printed:

```
{'error': {'status': 400,
  'message': 'Only valid bearer authentication supported'}}
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything! I am working on a school project that is due soon so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a `:` after `Bearer` in the header.